# Connect one app gateway to another app gateway in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I was wondering If I can connect two APPGW between them

This is my current infra

[image]

What I need to do is redirect traffic from External VM to the APPGW-C so that it then sends traffic to the APPGW-B and finally the traffic reaches VM-A

For achieving this, I added the private IP of the APPGW-B on the backend pool of my APPGW-C, but it throws me a 502 error.

Is it possible to connect two Application Gateways between them? My goal is redirecting traffic from one Application Gateway to another Application Gateway for finally send the traffic to a VM (as described in the image)

I hope everything is clear, any question feel free to ask it

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing a 502 error when accessing the first App Gateway it is very likely this backend pool member is being marked as 'unhealthy'.  If it's marked as healthy, the 502 could be coming from the second App Gateway having an unhealthy backend.

In either case, the backend health is dependent on probe response.  By default, a probe will be sent based on the port and protocol (HTTP or HTTPS) of your Backend Settings to the backend pool members (in this case, another App Gateway) and if the response, if any, has a status code of 200-399 it will be marked as healthy.  Also, this default probe sends a hostname of "127.0.0.1" to the backend server which cannot be sent as SNI over HTTPS per RFC 6066.  A failed TLS connection to a backend pool member or certificate related issue will cause it to be marked as unhealthy as well.

This is the default probe configuration and you actually won't see any probes listed in the Portal unless you create a custom one.

A few questions to narrow down the cause for the 502's:

- Is this a V1 or V2 App Gateway?
- If you see the backend marked as 'unhealthy' does it tell you why?
- Is the frontend of your second App Gateway (behind the first) using HTTP or HTTPS on the listener?  The backend settings and probes of your first App Gateway must match this for normal traffic and health checks respectively to work.

For probe configurations docs see here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-probe-overview

Comment: I managed to resolve this issue. But now, I'm trying to add one private ip and one public ip to the same listener but I'm not finding the approach

Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem!  Unfortunately you cannot assign multiple IP's or ports to the same listener.  You could, however, create a new listener and rule that point to the same backend pool with the same backend settings and use that instead.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of experience with this! I'll try your approach and come back when I have more info about it! 

For now my infra is (it changed a bit):

One vnet where my AKS Cluster is, another vnet where my app gateway and API Management Service are and, finally, one more vnet where my VPN Gateway is.

Basically, one external provider needs to connect to our VPN for then, send the traffic to the app gateway that will redirect them to the API Management.

This is an excalidraw of the infra: https://imgur.com/a/9RGU7bQ